# C# error while accessing stored procedure to Insert into a table and return the ID

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am new to this. I am not sure how to format this to look correct.

Here is my procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.InsertItem

@Metal varchar(10),
@Purity varchar(10),
@Weight decimal(18,2),
@Description varchar(50),
@ModifiedBy varchar(50),
@ModifiedOn datetime,
@Identity bigint OUTPUT

AS

INSERT INTO Item VALUES(@Metal, @Purity, @Weight, @Description, @ModifiedBy, @ModifiedOn)
Set @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
RETURN
```

Here is my C# code accessing the procedure:

```
queriesAdapter.InsertItem(temp.metal, temp.purity, temp.weight, temp.description, currentEmployee.Username, DateTime.Now, ref itemID);
```

Here is the structure referred to by temp:

```
public struct ItemInformation
{
    public long id;
    public string metal;
    public string purity;
    public decimal weight;
    public string description;
    public bool fake;
    public bool stolen;
    public decimal amountPaid;
    public decimal estimatedValue;
}
```

`itemID` is a long data type

`currentEmployee.username` is a string

Here is the error message:

> The best overloaded method match for 'queriesAdapter.Insert(string, string, decimal?, string, string,
>   system.DateTime?, ref long?)' has some invalid arguments.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Can anybody give me some advice on how to fix this?

Comment: It might be a good idea to specify what technology you use to bind to the SP, because this isn't ADO.NET but some ORM...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this seems to be a simple problem - your itemID parameter should be a nullable long.  That insert method method is looking for **ref long**?, you're passing in **ref long**.

Comment: Thank you.  It was so simple, and I overlooked it.  This fixed the problem completely.